# How handle POST requests in slim framework?

Tags: php, post, slim

my **index.php** page is

```
//post  : The handler POST requests
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
require 'RedBean/rb.php';

// register Slim auto-loader
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
// do initial application and database setup
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=slim','root','root');
R::freeze(true);

// initialize app
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

// handle POST requests to /articles
$app->post('/articles', function () use ($app) {    
  try {
    // get and decode JSON request body
    $request = $app->request();
    $body = $request->getBody();
    $input = json_decode($body); 

    // store article record
    $article = R::dispense('articles');
    $article->title = (string)$input->title;
    $article->url = (string)$input->url;
    $article->date = (string)$input->date;
    $id = R::store($article);    

    // return JSON-encoded response body
    $app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    echo json_encode(R::exportAll($article));
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $app->response()->status(400);
    $app->response()->header('X-Status-Reason', $e->getMessage());
  }
});

// run
$app->run();
```

When i load the `index.php` i got **404 Page Not Found** this error.

`POST` request is used to create a new item.How can i provide data for item creation. My table structure is

```
table name: articles

id | title | url | date
```

I make working `GET`(for retreive data) request successfully.

So i don't know how to use `POST` request in `slim`. Please give me a specific solution for how to use `POST` requests.

Thanks..

Comment: What is your question? `"when i load index.php..."` what do you mean by that? You mean when you visit localhost in your browser, when you visit /articles? Is this your complete index.php?

Comment: @user574632,  http://localhost/dpu_bin/slim/index.php this page give the error as above mentioned.Yes this is the complete index.php as in my question

Comment: Did you try posting some data to your `/articles` through cURL ?

Comment: localhost/dpu_bin/slim/index.php/articles also give the same error

Comment: @1nflktd, no i don't know how to post data through cURL. is cURL is must?? How can i simply add data?

Answer (score 1):

If that is your complete index.php, then you do not have a route defined for ANY get requests, so loading the page in the browser will fail. Add the following before `$app->run();` an you will not get the error:

```
$app->get('/', function () {
    echo "Hello next2u";
});
```

I think you really need to read the documentation: http://docs.slimframework.com/

Comment: +1..ohk..thanks..the page is loaded. Now how can i create new item.In my code where and what change should i do?

Comment: in my index.php file there is no data for post.How can add data??

Comment: @next2u Well you need to POST the data. The use of json in the `/articles` function suggests its an api to be consumed by javascript, but thats just a guess, only you know where the data is supposed to come from. Is this someone elses project that you are working on?

Comment: here '/articles', in post request means what?simply how can i pass a json request through post.Currently in my index.php file there is no json object.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are accessing some route that doesn't exists.

When you access directly through the browser, you are sending a `GET` request, not a `POST` request, and the `GET` route doesn't exists in your app, that's why you get that error.

Take a look at cURL:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Or some plugin to firefox [RESTCLIENT](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/restclient/) or chrome [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) for sending `POST` and `PUT` requests to your app.